# Logback - Modifying DynamicThresholdFilter (TurboFilter) programmatically at runtime

Tags: logback

We are using logback with DynamicThreshholdFilter definition as given below

```
<turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.DynamicThresholdFilter">
   <Key>USER_MDC_KEY</Key>
   <DefaultThreshold>DEBUG</DefaultThreshold>
   <MDCValueLevelPair>
      <value>USER1</value>
      <level>DEBUG</level>
   </MDCValueLevelPair>
</turboFilter>
```

Is there a way to programmatically modify the setting of MDCValueLevelPair. For example, modifying the level of USER1 to INFO.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be **modified** dynamically because there's a check that prevents it.

You can, however, set it dynamically with something along the lines of:

```
Iterator<TurboFilter> it = ((ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()).getTurboFilterList().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  TurboFilter f = it.next();
  if (f instanceof DynamicThresholdFilter) {
    DynamicThresholdFilter dtFilter = (DynamicThresholdFilter)f;
    MDCValueLevelPair pair = new MDCValueLevelPair();
    pair.setValue("USER1");
    pair.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    dtFilter.addMDCValueLevelPair(pair);
  }
}
```

If you don't already have a `TurboFilter` configured, you can just create a new one and add it to the `LoggerContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Since it cannot be modified, so when we add another MDCValueLevelPair, would it override the earlier value

Comment: If you try adding another `MDCValueLevelPair` with the same value, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add another MDC Key/Value pair to control log level rather than changing the log level for USER1.

```xml
<configuration>
  <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.DynamicThresholdFilter">
    <Key>LEVEL_FOR_USER1</Key>
    <DefaultThreshold>DEBUG</DefaultThreshold>
    <MDCValueLevelPair>
      <value>INFO</value>
      <level>INFO</level>
    </MDCValueLevelPair>
  </turboFilter>
  ......
</configuration>
```

```java
MDC.put("LEVEL_FOR_USER1", "INFO");
```